# Why do film about the Holocaust tend to focus on the mystery of goodness rather than the horror of mass murder?

Tags: film-industry

Why do film about the Holocaust tend to focus on the mystery of goodness rather than the horror of mass murder? For example: Schindler's List, The Pianist, Europa Europa, etc...

Comment: It's hard to ensure a good box office result when 'everyone (we are asked to care about) dies'..

Comment: Yea, super downer movies rarely test well. Unless you want a snuff film, then you may hit NC17 rating.

Comment: People need a source of hope, when there seems no possibility of any such thing!

Answer (score 1):

These movies are just like movies, they are telling a story. If a film would focus on the horror of the mass murder, it would just be a documentary, and there are plenty of those, which are really exhaustive. In almost every movies, there is a hero that you can like, or an anti-hero that you can learn to like, or at least an opposition between two camps. In a movie about the holocaust, you would just see how they were killing people, from the point of view of a narrator or maybe some German soldier.

If you want to see a movie like what I described, I advise you to see *Night and fog* (*Nacht und Nebel* in German or *Nuit et Brouillard* in French, because it's French), which was released in 1955.

[Wikipedia link to Night and Fog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_and_Fog_(1955_film))

[image: French jacket of Nacht und Nebel]

Or if you want original footage, you can find plenty of videos in the internet.

Here one:

[Youtube video of WWII footage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=345&v=vdba86U2g68)

Answer (score -1):

lmao I'm in HIS75 too. I think it's because the filmmaker may feel it his duty to give the audience a positive message (humanity is capable of the highest good and the worst evil) instead of just showing depressing reality for 2 hours. Europa Europa, The Pianist, and Schindler's List are all based on true stories though so it's not like the director has to fabricate a scenario. These stories happened to real people. Real people did terrible things and horrible things. The filmmakers are just telling the story like it is.